# Understanding the use of prime notation in a probability context

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to understand how to read the following

$\pi(z'|z)=Pr(z_{t+1}=z'|z_t=z')$

specifically, how is $'$ supposed to read as compared to $t+1$?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: We need more context. It's probably just relabeling a number.

Comment: There is probably a typo here (I'm assuming it should read $z_t = z$). What is the "prime notation" you are referring to here? $z,z'$ are just two different elements, $\mid$ refers to conditional probabilities, and the random variable is the sequence $(z_t)_{t}$.

Comment: that would be my assumption too :-)